# How to connect Opendaylight to Mininet?

Tags: java, maven, karaf, mininet, opendaylight

I've been working in a simple Hello World project to learn the basics for Opendaylight (I was following this [tutorial](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype#Part_2_-_Hello_World_-_Defining_a_Simple_RPC)).

Now I want to connect this build of the controller to a network topology defined by Mininet but this is not working. I read that this may be due to I haven't installed odl-l2switch but when I type `feature:list --installed` the bundle doesn't appear and when I type `feature:install odl-l2switch` it doesn't appear neither.

Perhaps it is because the way I created the project:

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.2-Boron-SR2`

This is strange because I downloaded the Carbon release and I could connect this distribution with Mininet and it worked. Initially I was going to build the hello project in Carbon, the latest distribution, but it didn't work so I did the Hello-World in Boron release.

Can anyone help me?

This is my [Github repository](http://github.com/Onishima/opendaylight_test)

Comment: You need to reference all required features (like l2-swotch) in features.xml and pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype#Part_1_-_Build_with_a_simple_.27Example.27_module), the command to generate an ODL app is :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/<Snapshot-Type>/ \
-DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=<Archetype-Version>
```

where you have to ***replace as following*** the proper  and :

- For the current Master (Carbon) use Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.snapshot Archetype-Version=1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
- For the Carbon snapshot use Snapshot-Type=**opendaylight.release** Archetype-Version=**1.3.0-Carbon**
- For Boron "SR0" use Snapshot-Type=**opendaylight.release** Archetype-Version=**1.2.0-Boron**
- For Boron SR1 use Snapshot-Type=**opendaylight.release** Archetype-Version=**1.2.1-Boron-SR1**
- For Boron SR2 use Snapshot-Type=**opendaylight.release** Archetype-Version=**1.2.2-Boron-SR2**
- For the Boron snapshot use Snapshot-Type=**opendaylight.snapshot** Archetype-Version=**1.2.2-SNAPSHOT**

The command you use uses **1.2.2-Boron-SR2** as , but as  you use `public`, which is not the appropriate . Replace `public` with `opendaylight.release`, as the above link suggests.

Comment: Glad that I helped! Would also be glad if you upvoted my answer, if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your ODL distribution , you have all the ODL projects which you can install it at anytime. To connect with mininet ,you have to install odl-l2switch-all feature.

In simple Hello project , you dont have l2switch feature to install. thats why you are not able to connect. Anyway you can install the l2switch feature by adding the l2switch dependency in Features/pom.xml and features.xml . You have to add the same odl version of l2switch.Be careful in this.

Please check feature:list | grep "l2switch" is available or not. If so, install it and launch the mininet !! You are done now  !