# Using OpenDaylight starter archetype does not work

Tags: maven, sdn, opendaylight

Trying to follow the opendaylight [developer tutorial](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html) to get an initial hello world application running on the controller, however running the command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \ -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ \ -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/archetype-catalog.xml
```

Results in an error

```
No plugin found for prefix ' -DarchetypeRepository=https' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/andrew/.m2/repository), opendaylight-snapshot (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/), opendaylight-mirror (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I've managed to get it to succeed using the command

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default) on project test-impl: You have 1 Checkstyle violation. -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default) on project test-impl: You have 1 Checkstyle violation. at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this (or other ways of getting a first app)?

Comment: It seems the tutorial is out dated. The problem is that archetypeCatalog 'https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/archetype-catalog.xml' is not supported anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in the OpenDaylight [forum](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/14478/unable-to-build-startup-project-using-published-documentation/).

> Please remove
>   `-DarchtypeCatlog=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/archetype-catalog.xml`
>
> and execute following command.
>
> `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0`

Comment: Any reason to use specific (old) version `1.2.2-Boron-SR2` ?

Comment: No specific reason. Thats a quote from that forum. Feel free to use the current version of that archetype

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype), you can use the following command :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/<Snapshot-Type>/ \
-DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=<Archetype-Version>
```

while replacing `Snapshot-Type` and `Archetype-Version` as follows:

Using [this search on ODL's Nexus repository](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/#nexus-search;gav~~opendaylight-startup-archetype~~~):

- For the `Oxygen dev snapshot` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.snapshot` and `Archetype-Version=1.5.0-SNAPSHOT`
- For the `Nitrogen SR1 snapshot` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.snapshot` and `Archetype-Version=1.4.1-SNAPSHOT`
- For the `Nitrogen release` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.release` and `Archetype-Version=1.4.0`
- For the `Carbon` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.release` and `Archetype-Version=1.3.0-Carbon`
- For `Boron SR0` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.release` and `Archetype-Version=1.2.0-Boron`
- For `Boron SR1` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.release` and `Archetype-Version=1.2.1-Boron-SR1`
- For `Boron SR2` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.release` and `Archetype-Version=1.2.2-Boron-SR2`
- For the `Boron snapshot` use `Snapshot-Type=opendaylight.snapshot` and `Archetype-Version=1.2.2-SNAPSHOT`

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591369/how-to-connect-opendaylight-to-mininet/45674232#45674232).