# opendaylight : maven archetype for Nitrogen release

Tags: opendaylight

I want to upgrade my opendaylight Java project to use the Nitrogen release. How can I generate the maven archetype for this? I was previously using the following to generate the archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.4-Boron-SR4 -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release
```

What archetypeVersion should be used for Nitrogen? Note: The mvn command above works fine for Carbon etc. However, I don't know what version to use for Nitrogen. The catalog does not seem to list a version for Nitrogen. i.e. I don't find a Nitrogen version here:
      https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/archetype-catalog.xml

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using OpenDaylight starter archetype does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054929/using-opendaylight-starter-archetype-does-not-work)

Comment: Not a duplicate -- I added clarifications above.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate, the answer in [Using OpenDaylight starter archetype does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054929/using-opendaylight-starter-archetype-does-not-work) gives: "Archetype-Version=1.4.0"

Comment: Yes - accepted as duplicate. Please close question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command for generating a framework for a nitrogen release. Use archetypeVersion=1.4.0.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069510/421602) for the list of the version numbers you can use for the opendaylight-startup-archetype.

Comment: Give some explanation of your solution.