# How to add built in features in an ODL developed application?

Tags: maven, sdn, opendaylight

For creating an ODL application, I have already built the application skeleton using maven as follows:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId= org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon
```

I am Confused which version I should be using in my ***"DarchetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon"***? Where can I find all available versions to be used?

I am planning to uses some features that are not existing by default, I understand that any additional feature, as l2switching or openflowplugin, is added by editing the **feature.xml** and the **pom.xml** files. I am still confused about using different versions. How to specify versions in my pox.xml file?

**I am editing the feature.xml file by adding more repository lines as follows:**

```
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.yangtools/features-yangtools/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.controller/features-mdsal/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository>
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.mdsal.model/features-mdsal-model/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.netconf/features-restconf/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.dluxapps/features-dluxapps/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.openflowplugin/features-openflowplugin/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
< repository > mvn:org.opendaylight.l2switch/features-l2switch/{{VERSION}}/xml/features < /repository >
```

**In the pom.xml file, looks like I need to add some dependency tags, but I am still confused what version to USE:**

```
<dependency >
    < groupId > org.opendaylight.l2switch < /groupId >
    < artifactId > features-l2switch< /artifactId >
    < classifier >features < /classifier >
    < type > xml < /type >
    < version > ${l2switch.version} < /version >
    < scope > runtime < /scope >
< /dependency >
```

Comment: I found this link interesting: https://nexus.opendaylight.org/#nexus-search;quick~yangtools-artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069510/421602 lists the version numbers you can use for the opendaylight-startup-archetype.  You can indeed also just check the repository, but the correct link to see all versions of that archetype would be https://nexus.opendaylight.org/#nexus-search;quick~opendaylight-startup-archetype (not yangtools-artifacts).

As for confusion re. versions in feature.xml and the pom.xml files, the best is to either look at the archetype example projects, or find the right version by looking at the appropriate branch in the OpenDaylight source code.  For example, if you wanted to know what the correction version of say l2switch for ODL's Carbon release was, you could have a look at e.g. https://github.com/opendaylight/l2switch/blob/stable/carbon/artifacts/pom.xml to find 0.5.3-SNAPSHOT (or use 0.5.2).

FYI: As far as I know the archetype for the Nitrogen release is broken at the time of writing this; so I would just use the latest bleeding edge Oxygen, for the archetype and projects like l2switch or whatever you are interested in.

Comment: do you mean by using the l2switch project, to just install the l2switch feature in the pom.xml and feature.xml. or download the whole project. Also, if I used the oxygen will I be able to know the versions of these features from  https://nexus.opendaylight.org/#nexus-search;quick~opendaylight-startup-archetype

Comment: To decide between adding the l2switch feature in the pom.xml and feature.xml and downloading the whole project, that depends if you want to have the source code of l2switch to contribute to it (or even just look around it to understand it better), or if you just want to "use" it in your project. And yes if you used the oxygen will I be able to know the versions of these features from nexus.opendaylight.org.